# All elements are replaced by last element in an arraylist of hashmap

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have values as

Question Q-id
Q1        1
Q2        2
...and so on

I want to retrieve them by calling a function. So i used an arraylist of HashMaps as follows..

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllQuestions(Integer id)
 {
     try
     {
         HashMap<String,String> QuesList = new HashMap<String,String>();
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> QuestionArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         // Select All Query
         String selectQuery = <some query here>;

          cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

         // looping through all rows and adding to list
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
         {
             do 
             {

                 QuesList.put("ques_id", cursor.getString(2));
                 QuesList.put("ques_text", cursor.getString(8));
                 QuestionArrayList.add(QuesList);
                 Log.i("ques",cursor.getString(8) );
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }


         Log.i("check"," Ques list returned");
         return QuestionArrayList;

     }
     catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
     {
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
         throw mSQLException;
     }
 }
```

Now the Logcat shows that all questions are retrieved successfully at the time of individual fetch (as shown by the Log.i statement) but whe i run the following loop at the end all the elements are replaced by the last fetched question. Any help is much appreciated.

```
   for(HashMap<String, String> t : QuesList )
    {
        Log.d("out there", "count" + t.getString());
        Log.i("mapping....",t.get("ques_id"));
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call the `add` method, only the reference to the object is added. So next time you modify the object, the reference refers to the modified object and the old state of the object is not retained.

In your case, you will have to create new objects every time you want to add them to the `List`:

```
     // looping through all rows and adding to list
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
     {
         do 
         {
             //Create a new object instance of the Map
             HashMap<String,String> QuesList = new HashMap<String,String>();

             QuesList.put("ques_id", cursor.getString(2));
             QuesList.put("ques_text", cursor.getString(8));
             QuestionArrayList.add(QuesList);
             Log.i("ques",cursor.getString(8) );
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
```

Comment: Although it is the issue, there is a more fundamental problem: there should not be a list in the first place.

Comment: @assylias: I wouldn't be so sure about that. The question does not state how the resulting data structure is to be used. Maybe the consuming API requires this kind of layout.

Comment: @JanHudec That is a possibility but I think it is worth mentioning in case it is not the reason.

Comment: @assylias What alternative do you suggest apart from this. I want to get these values to another activity and then display them one at a time with their id's.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that, inside your loop, you are only using a single instance of Questlist which is added in the QuestionArrayList.

Try moving

```
 HashMap<String,String> QuesList = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

inside  the loop.

```
 do 
         {

             HashMap<String,String> QuesList = new HashMap<String,String>();

             QuesList.put("ques_id", cursor.getString(2));
             QuesList.put("ques_text", cursor.getString(8));
             QuestionArrayList.add(QuesList);
             Log.i("ques",cursor.getString(8) );
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a list here, use the map to store all your key/value pairs:

```
QuesList.put(cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(8));
```

Will store your questions in the map. You can then loop:

```
for(String q : QuesList.values()) {…}
```

Ps: your problem is that you only use one map and keep using the same key, overriding previous entries.

Comment: The structure in the question indeed looks suboptimal, but it may be required by the consuming API or there may be more more entries in each map in the list or the order of the entries might be important or some other thing, so your suggestion may or may not be valid.