# android - all array objects are replaced with the last object within the iteration

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, loops

I am getting 3 different rows from db. When I try to set contents of these rows into the array, I get same values for each index. I am sure that the data is coming from db correctly. But after the loop, it gives me an array whose contents of indexes are same

Here is the code

```
       QuizWord[] words=new QuizWord[4]; 
       words[0]=word; // this "word" object is defined somewhere in the page,don't care 

     Cursor cursorOther=null;

    cursorOther=db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM words WHERE id  NOT  IN ('"+trueId+"') ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3",null);

    int i=1;
    if(cursorOther.moveToFirst()){
        while (cursorOther.moveToNext()) {

            QuizWord tempWord = new QuizWord();
            tempWord.setId(cursorOther.getInt(0));
            tempWord.setTr(cursorOther.getString(1));
            tempWord.setEn(cursorOther.getString(3));
            tempWord.setAr(cursorOther.getString(2));

            tempWord.setGroup_id(Integer.parseInt(cursorOther.getString(4)));
            words[i] = tempWord;
            Log.v("i-->",String.valueOf(i));
            Log.v("current word --_>",tempWord.toString());

            i++;


        }
        cursorOther.close();

    }
```

end of the loop, each indice of array has same object (the last object of the cursor)

Comment: What's the output in your log?

Comment: looks like you are messed with array somewhere later. Please, bring a code which checks array content, and what exactly in the log

Comment: `07-07 01:01:41.136  12009-12009/com.foo.foo V/i-->﹕ 1
    07-07 01:01:41.136  12009-12009/com.foo.foo V/current word --_>﹕ {"group_id":1,"tr":"girmek","en":"enter, come in"}
    07-07 01:01:41.136  12009-12009/com.foo.foo V/i-->﹕ 2
    07-07 01:01:41.136  12009-12009/com.foo.foo V/current word --_>﹕    {"group_id":1,"tr":"i&ccedil;mek","en":"drink"}
    07-07 01:01:41.136  12009-12009/com.foo.foo V/i-->﹕ 3
    07-07 01:01:41.141  12009-12009/com.foo.foo V/current word --_>﹕ {"group_id":1,"tr":"yazmak","en":"write"}`

Comment: Means that ,as I said, the data comes from db correctly. When I debug the app , in each loop, all datas of the array are set to the current object

Comment: There is a similar problem on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067579/all-elements-are-replaced-by-last-element-in-an-arraylist-of-hashmap) link but I am creating a new object in each iteration